# my python function is not recognizing my dynamic variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a df.loc() function passing in a dynamic variable.  I have managed to isolate my 5 different dynamic variables and split them. I am trying to use a for loop to run my function on each of the 5 variables.

All 5 of my dynamic variables are stored in `li`, below is the for loop I am using to call my function on all 5 variables.

```
for i in li:
    dataframe(i)
```

and here is the function I am passing it too

```
def dataframe(x):
    df = pd.read_pickle('url_cpa') 
    print(x) 
    df = df.loc[(df.Advertiser == x) , ['Spend','Date'])
    df = df.set_index('Advertiser')
    print(df)
    return df
```

If I hardcode one of my variables into the function it runs and returns the dataframe I want

```
 in: df = df.loc[(df.Advertiser == 'Advertiser 1') , ['Spend','Date'])
out: 
  'Advertiser 1' 
      Advertiser               Spend             Date
      Advertiser 1             101.3              10/12/16
      Advertiser 1             54.2               10/5/16
```

however when I subsitute in my variable x like it is below, it returns a blank dataframe

```
 in: df = df.loc[(df.Advertiser == x ) , ['Spend','Date'])
out: 
 'Advertiser 1'
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Spend, Date]
Index: []
```

when I simply print out my variable x in the function it returns the correctly formatted variable

```
 in: print(x) 
out: 'Advertiser 1'
```

I can't figure out why the `df.loc()` command returns an empty dataframe when called on my variable x, but returns a populated dataframe when I hard code the variable.

Comment: Please post code that reproduces the problem. For example, what is `li`?

Comment: try printing the representation, jsut to rule out any weird funny characters: `print(repr(x))`

Comment: @T_J_P : In the `loc` selection when you include `['Spend','Date']`, only those columns get returned when the condition gets satisifed. Later, you are reusing `'Advertiser'` column to set it as the index axis which doesn't really exist. Inorder to accommodate that, you need to append this column to the returned list of columns during `loc` selection, like - `['Spend','Date','Advertiser']`.

Comment: @NickilMaveli I tried to implement your change, my `loc` statement now reads like this  `df = df.loc[(df.Advertiser == x) , ['Advertiser','Date','Spend']}`  but I am still having the same issue where it returns an empty dataframe. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @NickilMaveli I also tried `df = df[df['Advertiser'] == x]` which should do a similar function but still empty df's are returned.  I think the issue has to do with the `x` variable not storing the value correctly.